# Leaving academia for financial reasons - how to communicate the reason of departure in a professional manner?

Tags: communication, workplace, quitting, assistant-professor

I recently finished my PhD and continued to work at the same department as assistant professor. Amid lack of funding, and other academic joys, the department went an extra mile to procure my contract and I was assigned to interesting longterm projects. So from the academic perspective I should consider myself very lucky (most people fight for an uncertain short postdoc position), and the conditions for work are quite good in comparison to other departments in the field.

However, just a few months into the position, I decided to leave academia altogether, exclusively for financial reasons. I always accepted some pay gap in comparison to the industry, but recently I run into a few former classmates from undergrad, visited their companies to discuss collaborations, but suddenly ended up in getting a few job offers in comparison to which my current position looks quite inferior. The difference in the salary leaves me no option but to accept one of the offers. Also, since this happened I became quite demotivated to work.

I am expected to start in a few months. What would be the best communication strategy to my department? Considering that they did quite a lot, and I am in a position which looks perfect to them.

Unfortunately stating upfront the financial reason would be awkward and probably not understood, as talking about personal finances in most academic settings is frowned upon, and there is a culture which expects people to be happy with the academic salaries.

Comment: In my humble opinion, telling the truth is the best way even you'll be frowned upon. No offence intended, you must accept the consequence for the decision you make.

Comment: I would add to @scaaahu 's comment that (at least in the US) leaving academic and nonacademic jobs for better offers after a short period of time is relatively common.  Some colleagues will be upset and some will be understanding.

Comment: Have you actually signed a contract with the new job? Without a contract everything is just talk and talk is cheap.

Comment: Currently I do part-time risk-assessment to pay for school; I know my math professors could probably do this stuff in their sleep, but since they've spent their lives teaching people like me, I'm not even sure they make more than I do. I applaud you sticking around for so long. There is honor in the Academic's Vow of Poverty, but no shame pursuing the American Dream either.

Comment: Remember to crack a joke about the forces of corporate darkness on your way out though.

Comment: Would you do better to remain for 1 or 2 years, then get even better job offers?    E.g. get some experience that lets you go into a "normal" job at the level of a team leader?   Also consider what any pension etc is worth to you.   Also consider travel and housing costs depending on the location of the job.

Comment: _Unfortunately stating upfront the financial reason would be awkward_ — Honesty is often awkward, but still necessary.

Comment: it's country dependent but "They offered me far far more money" doesn't seem like an unreasonable reason to leave. You're not a monk. You're allowed to have hopes and dreams for your personal life. Discussing personal finance may be frowned upon but they all know that most of them wouldn't be there if they weren't getting paid.

Comment: "The difference in the salary leaves me no option but to accept one of the offers." - Assuming you can live from the academic salary and aren't continously on the brink of poverty, this "justification" is none. - Academia doesn't make people rich, you don't stay in it for the money. Yes, people have to live - and without a wage that you can live from I can't see you or anybody else staying in academia, but outside of that, money is not the prime motivator for anybody in an academic positon.  (Aside from maybe the odd "high flying" professor or people in upper management of the university.)

Comment: I think you are doing others a disservice by **NOT** mentioning the pay gap as the main difference. Management may never think there is a problem if no one ever says anything about it.

Comment: "I am leaving the department because nunya"

Comment: @HannoverFist While you are technically right, it is highly unlikely that anything would change. The universities in the UK could do with at least 20% more staff - do you think anything changes? Of course not.

Comment: @DetlevCM I see your point, and money indeed shouldn't be a prime motivator, but I cannot agree when the gap is too large. Especially in the case when the (much) higher paying position requires less work and less hours.

Comment: @HannoverFist, that works only in industry. Unfortunately in academia salaries are pretty fixed and there is not much room for negotiation.

Comment: Do you have teaching obligations? If so, communicate *now*. The department needs time to adjust for your leaving.

Comment: @Joe443 That's how it is and it is unlikely to change - even more so given the continuous decline of science and education funding. (Apart from lighthouse projects where the money seems to misteriously vanish... - or at least no-one outside of management/the professors knows where it is going)
Academia cannot pay higher wages even if it wanted to, because it does not have the funds to do so.

Comment: "The difference in the salary leaves me no option but to accept one of the offers" the offers have not lowered your salary, if it was enough to happily live on before it is enough to live on afterwards. It is awkward to express your reasons because the truth is, the difference is greed. I think it is generally well understood that academia pays less and that people have made the choice to be there for other reasons.  It is fine if that choice isn't right for you.

Comment: @JamesRyan normally I would agree with you, but what if the academic work requires double the hours for half the pay... I don't think it's a good choice for a (rational) reason.

Comment: @Joe443 I'm sure the ratio is much higher than that for a lot of fields

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Express that you have enjoyed working in your department. (Even if this is not entirely true.)
2. Explain that you are only leaving because of an opportunity "too exciting to turn down." Don't volunteer exactly *why* it is exciting; if asked, talk about what you'll be *doing*, not what you'll be paid.
3. If there's a way you can help the department while you're in industry -- serving on a committee, helping with accreditation, accepting an intern, things like that -- it would be kind of you (though it is not obligatory) to volunteer unasked.
4. Keep your resignation letter short and cordial.

These tactics should suffice to keep your departure as amicable as it can be, assuming you're doing the normal things to minimize disruption (e.g. not leaving mid-term).

Comment: Points 1, 2, and 4 works for *any* situation, not just academia. Succinct, appreciative, and direct.

Comment: OK answer but I think (3) implies way too much debt. You don't owe them your soul. You're free to leave. Leave means leave, it doesn't mean donate them free time and effort and money as some sort of tithe going forward.

Comment: @djechlin: I disagree. The OP mentioned that the department had gone the extra mile for them. While one shouldn't feel *obligated* to pat the department's back in return (*certainly* not as part of leaving), I think it would do well to keep doors open. If you've got a good relationship with people in academia OR industry, it often pays to maintain those contacts. Internships and accreditation help with your own brand and reputation. Lastly, a big perk to employing a PhD grad is that they are well-connected, and can thus offer the company some additional think-power from their friends.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @djechlin Fair point; edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Winston Churchill, or perhaps it was Benjamin Disraeli, wrote: "Never apologise, never explain."

It is sufficient when resigning from any employment engagement to simply state that fact together with the effective date.  A cordial thanks for the opportunities afforded at your present position together with an expression of appreciation for the colleagues that you have encountered there are customary when appropriate and are best omitted when not.

There is no requirement to provide any further details whatsoever. Offering vague platitudes respecting 'other opportunities' in their place simply state the obvious and often prove more awkward for both the writer and the reader than anything else.

Comment: I've found a short explanation is better than none.  For example, "a deal I couldn't refuse, and exciting project with great pay" goes over a LOT better than no explanation.  Give people something they can identify with.

Comment: Most people appreciate some kind of explanation.  Perhaps you don't owe them anything, but they're still human beings, and they have helped out in the past.  It's decent to give them a bit of explanation, it will make them happier.

Comment: It is my experience that most people change jobs for a number of conflated reasons.  No one reason predominates except perhaps in retrospect.  I deeply suspect that had the OP been given a tenure track position that the impetus to consider other opportunities would have been much diminished if not altogether absent.   In my opinion this is the crux of his desire not to reveal the 'real' reason for leaving.  It is not about the money in the end. This is really about the uncertainty of his future.  In these circumstances the less said the better.